# How to concat and minify Javascript files really easily?

Tags: web, gruntjs, gulp, concatenation, minify

I'm teaching web development to beginners, and I want to show them how to concat and minify their Javascript files.

There are plenty of tutorials online on how to "concat and minify" with Grunt or Gulp, but they require a lot of installations & configurations. This is too complex for my needs.

Do you know any really simple way to do that? Something like a simple command line script to run manually:

```
> ./concatAndMinify foo.js bar.js output.js
```

I've been looking for hours with no success... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is with browserify and uglify:

```
browserify mainFile.js | uglifyjs > concatenatedFile.js
```

Install first those two dependencies and you're golden:

```
npm install -g browserify
npm install -g uglify-js
```

Of course you need to have all files inside mainFile required like this:

```
require('file1');
require('file2');
```

With gulp you will have to deal with additional file just for gulp configuration (a.k.a. gulp tasks) but if you want to go with gulp I can also write an easy gulpfile for concatenating files.